# SQL Server Sequence constant restarting

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking at a pattern where a SQL Server sequence is being used as a sub-index of records, and getting reset with each new set of records.

Something like:

```
create sequence dbo.MySequence start with 1 increment by 1;
create table dbo.Addresses (
    PersonID int
    ,AddressSequence int
    ,StreetAddress varchar(100)
);
    
declare @PersonID int;
set @PersonID = 1;
alter sequence dbo.MySequence restart with 1;
insert dbo.Addresses (PersonID, AddressSequence, StreetAddress)
values (@PersonID, next value for dbo.MySequence, '123');
insert dbo.Addresses (PersonID, AddressSequence, StreetAddress)
values (@PersonID, next value for dbo.MySequence, '456');

set @PersonID = 2;
alter sequence dbo.MySequence restart with 1;
insert dbo.Addresses (PersonID, AddressSequence, StreetAddress)
values (@PersonID, next value for dbo.MySequence, '789');

PersonID    AddressSequence StreetAddress
----------- --------------- ---------------
1           1               123
1           2               456
2           1               789
```

With each new person, the sequence is altered back to 1. In some scenarios, this would obviously be no good. In this particular scenario, records are only inserted one time and never edited, only by this one application, no parallelism/threading, and always with all addresses inserted before moving on to the next person.

Seems like it will work just fine, given the existing scenario. Of course this means we can never change those requirements, like having multiple processes do inserts at the same time.

But assuming all that is ok, is there something here that would hurt us? I'd expect altering a database object takes a little bit more work than just incrementing or resetting an in-memory variable, but are there any other gotchas I should look into or pass on to the DBA?

Comment: A `SEQUENCE` doesn't seem like the right choice here. `ROW_NUMBER` or `RANK` would be far better.

Comment: I would suggest just providing the AddressSequence value with each insert.

Comment: @Larnu I'm guessing you mean using row_number when querying the table on demand, rather than pre-populating the table when inserting. Which would require a separate incremental column to ensure the order remains consistent, so a sequence or identity would be required anyway for that. I agree that would seem to be a better option.

Answer (score 2):

There's no simple, efficient, scalable way to do this.  You should just allow the AddressSequence to increment across PersonIDs.  It's functionally equivilent for most purposes.  eg

```
PersonID    AddressID       StreetAddress
----------- --------------- ---------------
1           1               123
1           2               456
2           3               789
2           4               789
```

With PK (PersonID,AddressID).

And for display purposes you can always produce the AddressSequence with an expression like `row_number() over (partition by PersonID order by AddressID)`

Comment: Plus one, because this is the correct answer as things are. But I have also often wished for just such a "partitioned sequence" feature, even though I know it doesn't exist, but this is **NOT** not functionally equivalent in all things. For example, if you have more than ~2 billion of them over time, or if you need to mimic behavior in a prior system that used code to do this this rather than DB features.

Comment: You can roll over the sequence so long as you don't have a single-column key

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn "Partitioned sequence" - thank you, I was racking my brain trying to think of the correct term for this and was drawing a blank.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thank you - this makes sense.

Comment: @JoeEnos There is no correct term for this, because it's (unfortunately, imo) not a thing DBs do.

Comment: I would call it a sub-sequence.  It would be a challenge to implement without adversely affecting performance or concurrency.